# How do I use component state as props in another non-child component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a form inside of a component that adds items to an array when submitted using useState. I want to use these array values as options in a select input of another component. The problem is that there's not a parent-child relationship. What would be the best way to go about this?

The component generating `processes` array:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

function AddProcessForm () {

    const {register, handleSubmit, watch, errors} = useForm();
    const [processes, setProcesses] = useState([]);
    const onSubmit = data => {
        setProcesses(processes => [...processes, data])
        console.log(data)
        document.getElementById("process-entry-form").reset();
        }

    useEffect(() =>{
        console.log(processes);
    })

    return (
        <Form id="process-entry-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Form.Group controlId="" className="mx-2">
            <Form.Label>Add Process</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control name="processname" type="text" placeholder="Enter Process Name" ref={register}/>
          </Form.Group>
          <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="mb-2">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form>
    )
}

export default AddProcessForm;
```

The component that needs to use `processes` as select options:

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

function ActivitytoProcessInput () {

    return (
        <Form.Group controlId="" className="mx-2">
        <Form.Label>Belongs to Process</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="select">
                <option value="" selected>Select a Process</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
    )
}

export default ActivitytoProcessInput;
```

Comment: I would probably handle this in a common ancestor component

Comment: If those components are not related, or pretty far from each other in a parent/child chain, I'd probably use a state management lib like redux to handle this kind of "globally-used" state.

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica how do you pass state up from a component?

Comment: You don't. You hold state in the parent and pass it down to the children. You use events to alter the state in the parent. But if these components are far away from each other, then you might be better off with @NicolasSEPTIER's suggestion.

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica Really it's just two forms with the output of one form supplying the select list in the other. Since they are displayed together, I could put them inside of a container component. Then I would have `container` to hold the state, `form1` create an event to alter the state, and `form2` would use the state as props. Does that make sense?